# set dataprovider in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a datagrid w/ dataProvider property set in MXML as:

```
dataProvider="{pagedResult.lastResult}"
```

How do I set the dataprovider in actionscript? I have:

```
protected function getResult (event:FlexEvent):void
{
pagedResult.token = mydata.paged();
adg1.dataProvider = pagedResult.lastResult;
}
```

but I'm doing something wrong as it does not work

Comment: The dataProvider class has to be given a collection object e.g. ArrayCollection, XMLListCollection. Convert your last result into one of these and make it [Bindable] when you create the var.

Comment: @Brian Bishop That isn't true.  In Flex 3, any object can be used as a dataProvider.  Although there may be reasons to use collections, that is not the only thing that can be accepted.  In Flex 4, dataProvider's I'm pretty sure that dataProvider's must implement the IList interface.

Comment: @Flextras Ah right, thought it was. Looked it up and saw that its considered best practice to use an ArrayCollection/XMLListCollection, but not mandatory. Adobe on DataProviders: "Using collections explicitly ensures data synchronization and provides both simpler and more sophisticated data access and manipulation tools..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks solid, I guess the issue is that you need to convert it.  You didn't say what sort of data your service is returning, but for the purposes of this sample I'll assume an Array

Try something like this

```
var myCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(pagedResult.lastResult as Array);
adg1.dataProvider = myCollection;
```

Answer (score -1):

First if you are going to set the dataProvider from Actionscript I would remove the binding from the MXML, or you could just update the property that is bound but I do not know it's type so I will assume you have no problem removing the binding from the MXML tag.

Second as another answer mentioned you will want to convert your results to an ArrayCollection, you can find some useful functions in the *mx.utils.ArrayUtil* class.

Lastly it is important when working with large datasets you should update the ArrayCollection directly rather than always creating a new one. The list/datagrid will automatically redraw and update, optimally, without you having to worry about it as long as you add/remove/etc through your newly created ArrayCollection.